# NGINX not evaluating variables?

Tags: nginx, rate-limiting

I have a following nginx config:

```
http {
(...)

limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=limitapinoauth:16m;
limit_conn_zone $remote_user zone=limitapi:32m;

map $remote_user $zone {
    default   'limitapi';
    ''        'limitapinoauth';
}

map $zone $num {
    'limitapi'   100;
    default    200;
}

server {
    listen 80 default;

    root /var/www/example.com/public_html;

    limit_conn $zone $num;
}
(...)
}
```

Expected behavior is that mapped variables are evaluated to use in last line, but they aren't. Any idea why?

I get the following error:

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid number of connections "$num"
```

When I change $num to integer, i.e. 200, the error is:

```
nginx: [emerg] zero size shared memory zone "$zone"
```

If I change last line to:

```
limit_conn limitapi 100;
```

the config is correct.

Answer (score 2):

It is not stated clearly in the `ngx_http_map_module` [`map` Directive](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) documentation, which only says:

> Creates a new variable whose value depends on values of one or more of
>   the source variables specified in the first parameter.

I suppose that as `ngx_http_map_module`[.c](https://github.com/phusion/nginx/blob/master/src/http/modules/ngx_http_map_module.c) works in [The Module Context](http://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide.html#context) `ngx_http_map_create_conf` (while creating main configuration) and all indexed variables are [added](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/extending/api/variables/#ngx-http-add-variable) during pre-configuration, only [built-in variables](https://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html) can be used as source variables for the `map` directive. *(Nginx guru, please confirm.)*

Also, I couldn't find any example that uses a variable defined by `map` directive as a source variable on another `map` directive, which suggests the same. Therefore, I'd advice to create both variables, `$zone` and `$num`, directly based on the `$remote_user` variable.

```
map $remote_user $zone {
    default   'limitapi';
    ''        'limitapinoauth';
}

map $remote_user $num {
    default   100;
    ''        200;
}
```